# ng-model is not working inside a ui bootstrap modal window and angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using this modal window using angular and bootstrap ui

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Cambia Palmare {{descPalmare}} ( {{descProgetto}} )</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul>
                    <li >
                        <select id="soluzioneDlg" name="soluzioneDlg"
                                class="required"
                                ng-options="soluzione.id as soluzione.denominazione for soluzione in soluzioni"
                                ng-model="soluzioneCorrente"
                                ng-change="filtroSoluzione()"></select>
                    </li>
                        <select id="progettoDlg" name="progettoDlg"
                                class="required"
                                ng-options="progetto.id as progetto.denominazione for progetto in progetti"
                                ng-model="progettoCorrente"></select>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>
```

I'm opening the dialog  correctly and the soluzioneDlg select is filled correctly.
When the selection is changed, the filtroSoluzione method is correctly called but the scope variable bound using ng-model is undefined.

```
    $scope.filtroSoluzione = () => {
        alert($scope.soluzioneCorrente);
        var progettoPromise = progetti.progettiSoluzione($scope.soluzioneCorrente);
        progettoPromise.then(function (progetti: Factories.Progetto[]) {
            $scope.progetti = progetti;
        },
            function (reason) {
                alert('errore in recupero lista dispositivi: ' + reason);
            }, function (update) {
                alert('Got notification: ' + update);
            });

    }
```

Am I missing something? I used this code in other pages and is working correctly.
Thanks,
  Luca

this is the angular code that calls the $modal.open

```
    // cambia assegnazione, apro la finestra di assegnazione
    $scope.cambiaAssegnazione = (palmare: number) => {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: assegnaDispIspettoreDialog,
            size: '(large)',
            resolve: {
                palmareDaAggiornare: function () {
                    return palmare;
                },
                dispositivi: function () {
                    return dispositivi;
                },
                soluzioni: function () {
                    return soluzioni;
                },
                progetti: function () {
                    return progetti;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selectedItem = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
            alert('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    }
```

when I click a link in a list the mg_chnage change this code that open the dialog: in the resolve I send the reference of a few services I created, because I have to fill the listbox in the modal dialog.
the **descPalmare**, **descProgetto** and **soluzioni** scope properties are handled correctly: the only problem is in the **soluzioneCorrente** member

I created the full repro here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/G8qygJWkYCqiYZK5FcgN

Comment: Could you post the whole code for $modal?

Answer (score 0):

The modal uses a child scope, see [Understanding Scopes in the Angular.js Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). Try changing the ng-model for both in the page and in the modal to `model.soluzioneCorrente` instead and set the `scope` property of the `$modal.open` to the current `$scope`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/h3HIeM7oDwo42LK3CZie?p=preview